# Environment variables validation in heroku app

Tags: validation, heroku, express

Do I need to make a validation of environment variable before using it in heroku app ?

As a usual programming practice we should do validation of anything that could be wrong but specific technologies could have theirs own idioms and I'm interesting in best practices for apps that are deployed on heroku.

For example in express application if validation is performed then I display error page with the name of uninitialized variable:

```
app.get('/login', function(req, res) {
    if (!process.env.OAUTH2_SERVER) {
        res.render('env_error', { envVar : 'OAUTH2_SERVER' });
    } else {
        res.render('login', { oauth2Server : process.env.OAUTH2_SERVER});
    }
});
```

and without validation it looks like this:

```
app.get('/login', function(req, res) {
    res.render('login', { oauth2Server : process.env.OAUTH2_SERVER}); 
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would make more sense to do the validation on app startup, as any changes to Heroku ENV variables means a redeploy.
Here's some thirty second code to do it:

```
var checkEnv = ['OAUTH2_SERVER', 'other env var you care about', 'and so on'];
checkEnv.forEach(function (v) {
  if (typeof process.env[v] === "undefined") {
    console.err('Required environment variable "' + v '" is not present. Exiting.');
    process.exit(1);
  }
});
```

You could change the if on line 3 to check `process.env[v] === undefined` depending on which you think is cleaner.

**Edit** You should use the latter, it [benchmarks faster](http://jsperf.com/comparing-undefined-typeof-vs-equals).